# stuck with firebase_token.java

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-notifications

I have an errors with firebase_token.java

> error: cannot find symbol variable super
>
> error: cannot find symbol class FirebaseInstanceIdService
>
> error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

```
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService;


/**
 * Created by AQEEL on 5/22/2018.
 */

public class Firebase_Token extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        super.onTokenRefresh();
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        sharedPreferences= getSharedPreferences("userdata",MODE_PRIVATE);
        sharedPreferences.edit().putString("tokenid",refreshedToken).commit();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the supper annotation, and it will work fine

```
public class Firebase_Token extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        sharedPreferences= getSharedPreferences("userdata",MODE_PRIVATE);
        sharedPreferences.edit().putString("tokenid",refreshedToken).commit();
    }

}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for help reply. tried it and same problem, any idea?

Comment: mmm... aparently there's been some issues with firebase lately: https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Cloud%20Messaging/19005?fbclid=IwAR2QJGOds14F36LkfBcuoljCaycgy9Az43HjlAF8aLMbwGy6GmHLUK9TCfs   so i guess that maybe the reception of the token it's gonna have some problems, until they resolve it.